# I made a table view, how can I save the items even after the app is closed?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift2

I'm making my first app, and it has a task manager, for this, I made a table view in which you can input "tasks" through an alert. How can I save the inputted "tasks"? I did some research, however, I was not able to find an answer.
The code is the following:
(Swift 2)

```
import UIKit

class ThirdViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource{

var items: [String] = []
@IBOutlet weak var listTableView: UITableView!

@IBAction func additem(sender: AnyObject) {
alert()

}

@IBAction func savebtn(sender: AnyObject) {
print (items)

}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    listTableView.dataSource = self
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("listitem") as! ItemTableViewCell
    cell.itemLabel.text = items[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return items.count
}

func alert() {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "", message: "", preferredStyle: .Alert)

    alert.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler{
    (textfield) in
    textfield.placeholder = "Enter your task"
    }
    let add = UIAlertAction(title: "Add ", style: .Default) {
        (action) in
        let textfield = alert.textFields![0]
        self.items.append(textfield.text!)
        self.listTableView.reloadData()
        }
    let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel) {
        (alert) in

        print ("Hi")
    }
alert.addAction(add)
alert.addAction(cancel)

presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    items.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
    tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

}

}
```

Comment: Unrelated but if you are just starting out with Swift, why are you not using Swift 3? Swift 2 is out dated and not supported any more.

Comment: your question and your explanation is not synced. you said you want to save even after the app is closed. but you explained that you can't do saving data in tableview.which one is correct?

Comment: I would suggest you read about Core Data and use that; then your data will be saved "as you go"

Comment: You will find a lot of tutorials in Swift 3, but still if somehow you were only able to find them in Swift 2, I suggest you to not copy/paste the code, rather start typing the sytanx you see so that the compiler can **auto complete** the *new* syntax. But mostly the they're simple changes. To see a good overview of the changes see [here](https://buildingvts.com/a-mostly-comprehensive-list-of-swift-3-0-and-2-3-changes-193b904bb5b1)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether I'm understanding your question correctly, but I think it might help to read up on Apple's Tutorial and follow the "Persist Data" part.

(Link: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/PersistData.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH14-SW1)

It is a step-by-step tutorial that comes with detailed explanations. Should be able to you a good idea of how to save data for a simple app. (If a larger database is needed, Core Data is something to read about.)

Answer (score 1):

You can save any content local or in the cloud,

Local -> Core Data or Realm

Cloud -> Your custom API (obviously you are not ready for that) or Cloud API like (Firebase, Backendless)

Watch some tutorials for all of them, choose one for your purpose and vision about the app in the future.

Good luck.

Comment: also he can use [userDefaults](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/system/how-to-save-user-settings-using-userdefaults). But that's for saving small simple stuff. For a real persistence Core Data or Realm are much better

Answer (score 0):

```
The easiest way to Persist Data or store data even after your application is terminated or closed is use RMMapper,it work like nsuserdefaults but by using RMMapper we can store whole object..
//set
UserDefaults.standard.rm_setCustomObject(Obj1, forKey: "myObject")

//retrive

let obj = UserDefaults.standard.rm_customObject(forKey: "myObject")
```